# How can I enable my html page to check the user with two boolean field value and display their data using the "if" statement?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, jinja2

so I've created an account and I want to display details of that account. So I've used Boolean fields to regulate the data of each account on the html page, I didn't want to use filters because the application has specific functions that I didn't want complicate it with. I've created the Account_checker model that uses BooleanFields to regulate data. But if an account has two BooleanField=True, how can I display two information based on that two BooleanField=True on the HTML page?.

```
models.py
class Account_checker(models.Model):
    is_Type_A=BooleanField(default=False)
    is_Type_B=BooleanField(default=False)
    is_Type_C=BooleanField(default=False)

html page
{% for player in players %}
    {% if player .is_Type_A %}
       display type A data
    {% elif player.is_Type_B %}
        display type B data
    {% elif player.is_Type_C %} 
        display type C data
    {% elif player.is_Type_A and player.is_Type_B %} #This code isn't working
        display type A data and type B data
    {% elif player.is_Type_B and player.is_Type_C %} #This code isn't working
        display type B data and type C data
   {% elif player.is_Type_B and player.is_Type_C and player.is_Type_C %} #This code isn't working
        display type B data and type C data
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding parentheses between your conditions? I mean like that `{% elif (player.is_Type_A and player.is_Type_B) %}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working incorrectly because of your order of operations. Think of it logically, if the condition `{% elif player.is_Type_A and player.is_Type_B %}` is expected to execute, then that means logically `{% if player .is_Type_A %}` should execute as well (since `is_Type_A` is True)... but your double boolean is wrapped in an `elif`, which means it will **only** run if the conditions before it fail, which is not the case.

To make this work, you can either:
1) Reorder your code for your more complex conditionals to come first, so as not to short-circuit them.

2) Nest your conditions to have a cascading logical flow.

for example:

1)

```
{% for player in players %}
    {% if player.is_Type_A and player.is_Type_B and player.is_Type_C %}
        display type A, type B data and type C data
    {% elif player.is_Type_B and player.is_Type_C %}
        display type B data and type C data
    {% elif player.is_Type_A and player.is_Type_B %}
        display type A data and type B data
    {% elif player.is_Type_C %} 
        display type C data
    {% elif player.is_Type_B %}
        display type B data
    {% elif player.is_Type_A %}
       display type A data
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```